# sorting and creating text files from dataframe

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to make my life easier.I have a dataframe with several columns that will vary in size. Mainly it will be a 'gene' column and the rest will be expression numeric data for different patients/conditions. I want 1) sort by each of the numeric columns and 2) create files that include only the 'gene' column and each numeric column. I'm trying to generate a for loop for this. Using the mtcars built in database as an example I generated the following code:

```
mtcars

for (i in 2:ncol(mtcars)) {
  twocolumns <- data.frame(mtcars[,c(1,i)])
  write.csv(twocolumns, paste0(i,'.txt'), row.names = F)
}
```

this creates files with the names 1,2,3,4... '.txt'. How do I make these so they have the same name as the columns?

Also I haven't figured out the sorting part. So far i've tried this

```
mtcars <- mtcars[order(i),]
```

(Right before the 'twocolumns' line but this creates 1 row, 2 column files. )

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the names issue, replace the i with colnames(twocolumns[2])
Since you don't care about rownames, I used dplyr:: arrange to sort by col1 and col2 of each data frame.

```
mtcars
require(dplyr)
for (i in 2:ncol(mtcars)) {
    twocolumns <- data.frame(mtcars[,c(1,i)])
    twocolumns<-arrange(twocolumns,twocolumns[,1],twocolumns[,2])
    write.csv(twocolumns, paste0(colnames(twocolumns[2]),'.txt'), row.names = F)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually I only wanted to sort by column2 so I ommited the [,1] and only kept the [,2]. The other answer also works and is an alternative without using dplyr.

Comment: If you use R for any length of time, dplyr and other members of library(tidyverse) are your deep long lost friends you never knew you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in base R:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(mtcars)) {
  twocolumns <- data.frame(mtcars[,c(1,i)])
  write.csv(twocolumns[order(twocolumns[, 2]), ], paste0(colnames(mtcars)[i],'.txt'), row.names = F)
}
```

Explanation:
You want to order your `dataframe` based on the *values* of the second column, hence `twocoloumns[order(twocolumns[, 2]), ]`. `colnames(...)` returns a vector of the column names of the `dataframe`. Extract the *i*t entry with `colnames(...)[i]`.

Comment: Great suggestion. I didn't think of integrating the sorting (order) after creating the twocolumns. Thanks for the help! The other answer also works but it uses dplyr.